# Show progress Dialog while the UI gets customized

Tags: android, progressdialog

I already have idea on how to use a Progress Dialog when background action is being performed. But my question is how do I show a progress Dialog when I am dynamically inflating a huge layout.

Since I can't inflate a view in another Thread, I am using the main UI thread. Due to this my progress dialog is not getting priority and it doesn't show up. My UI hangs for several seconds until it gets loaded fully. I tried several approcahes but none seems to work.

```
        progress.show(context,"","inflating UI...");   
        setNewContent(R.layout.my_profile,R.id.my_profile_menu_button,R.id.my_profile_all_elements_layout);
                populateProfileList(); //Dynamic nested layouts being inflated.
```

I am basically looking for dynamic layout changes based on user actions. So I dont have any other way other than creating dynamic views. Can anyone suggest me a helpful idea.

Comment: can you please post the setNewContent Method

Answer (score 2):

I had an similar problem with ui-thread. I wanted to add much views to my layout at runtime, I wanted to show a ProgressDialog to inform the user, that it could take a while. I had tried it with AsyncTask, but the only chance to do this, was to implement my ui-methods into the onPostExecute-Method of AsyncTask. But this just freezes the ProgressDialog, because ProgressDialog even works on ui-thread. I found a solution, maybe not the best, but it works. Before starting ui-action, I show a Toast. Then, I created a Thread with a handler and delayed the execution. After ui-action was done, I showed a new Toast. Delay the thread, gives the Toast enough time to get showed:

```
    Toast.makeText(ActivityContext.this,
                  R.string.start_message,
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();

    final Thread uiThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

              @Override
           public void run() {

    uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

              @Override
          public void run() {

              yourUIAction();

              Toast.makeText(
                  ActivityContext.this,
                  R.string.finish_message,
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        

                            }
                          }, 100);
                  }
                });
     uiThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a handler to be able to talk to the UI thread

```
//in some thread
uiHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

...
Handler uiHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.what == 1) {
                //do somestuff
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I know I can use handlers. And I have used hanlders to update UI. But at this time the progressDialog just hangs up. It doesn't rotate anymore making it to look more nasty

Comment: so if  you put your progressDialog in a new thread and start it, and call the handler to inflate  your layout shouldnt that work?

Comment: I tried it and the progress wheel doesn't spin if I try it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Using Async Task is much better idea to me, when you have to do something in background, while progress dialog shows up on screen and then when background task completes, update UI... for reference please follow the link...

http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/

hope this helps...:-)

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I am not doing background actions. I am using main UI Thread to update UI. I can't use background thread for this.

Comment: Well, you may utilize the same idea... Inflate UI in BG and show spinner in front, when inflating function ends execution, remove spinner.